# ASP.NET Core Web API: Catching Routing Errors

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to catch routing errors in a ASP.NET Core Web API project.

To be specific, by routing error, I mean for example:
In the controller I only have:

```
// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

But a request is:

```
api/values/5/6
```

A 404 is returned automatically, but I would like to be able to handle this in code (i.e. invoke some kind of exception handling routine).

I have tried three different approaches without success:

In ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services), I added:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter));
});
```

This captures errors that occur within the controller (e.g. if I put a throw() in the Get(id) method above), but not routing errors.  I assume this is because no matching controller method was found so the error propagates up the middleware pipeline.

In an attempt to handle errors further up the pipeline I tried...

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseExceptionHandler(
        options =>
        {
            options.Run(
            async context =>
            {
                var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                // handle exception here
            });
        });

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I also tried:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // handle exception here
            }
        });

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Neither of the above appears to be invoked when a routing error occurs.  Am I taking the wrong approach?  Or should one of these approaches actually work?

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

PS.  I am relatively new to ASP.NET Web API, so please excuse where I may be using slightly the wrong terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UseStatusCodePages` extension method:

```
 app.UseStatusCodePages(new StatusCodePagesOptions()
 {
     HandleAsync = (ctx) =>
     {
          if (ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
          {
               //handle
          }

          return Task.FromResult(0);
     }
 });
```

**Edit**

```
 app.UseExceptionHandler(options =>
 {
       options.Run( async context =>
       {
             var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
             // handle
             await Task.FromResult(0);
       });
 });
 app.UseStatusCodePages(new StatusCodePagesOptions()
 {
     HandleAsync = (ctx) =>
     {
          if (ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
          {
               // throw new YourException("<message>");
          }

          return Task.FromResult(0);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer to capture an exception if possible - is this possible?  The approach here seems more like capturing the consequence after the event, rather than the capturing an exception when the problem occurs.

Comment: Why do you need an exception for 404 result?

Comment: Thanks.  In terms of the app.UseExceptionHandler() approach, I tried this (see the original question), but it doesn't seem to get called.  Do routing errors invoke the error handler?  (Starting to wonder whether routing errors cause exceptions at all).

Comment: Without an exception it is not called, because there is no exception for 404 . To use this you should manully throw exception. See my update.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's the bit I was struggling with.  I had assumed a routing error (resulting in a 404) would at some point in the request processing generate an exception.  So, basically, I was trying to catch an exception that never existed.  Thanks again.