# Route not found exception with the generic response model

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to capture the exception when the route is not found and wrap the exception with the **generic response model**.

I tried to implement, as given in the answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700607/asp-net-core-web-api-catching-routing-errors), but this solution also doesn't seem to work in my use case.

Because the status code 404 is also added to the response when the resource is not found, like when `Id is not found`.

```
 app.UseStatusCodePages(new StatusCodePagesOptions()
 {
     HandleAsync = (ctx) =>
     {
          if (ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
          {
                throw new RouteNotFoundException("Route not found");
          }

          return Task.FromResult(0);
     }
 })
```

**RouteNotFoundException**

```cs
public class RouteNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public RouteNotFoundException()
          : base()
    {
    }

    public RouteNotFoundException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

**ApiExceptionFilterAttribute**

```cs
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>> _exceptionHandlers;

        public ApiExceptionFilterAttribute()
        {
            // Register known exception types and handlers.
            _exceptionHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>>
            {
                { typeof(RouteNotFoundException), HandleNotFoundException }
            };
        }
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            HandleException(context);

            base.OnException(context);
        }
        private void HandleException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            Type type = context.Exception.GetType();
            if (_exceptionHandlers.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                _exceptionHandlers[type].Invoke(context);
                return;
            }

            HandleUnknownException(context);
        }
        private void HandleNotFoundException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            var exception = context.Exception as RouteNotFoundException;

            var details = new ProblemDetails()
            {
                Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
                Title = "The specified resource was not found.",
                Detail = exception.Message
            };

            context.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult(details);
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        private void HandleUnknownException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            var details = new ProblemDetails
            {
                Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                Title = "An error occurred while processing your request.",
                Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1"
            };

            context.Result = new ObjectResult(details)
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
            };

            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
}
```

**ResponseWrapperMiddleware**

```cs
public class ResponseWrapperMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ResponseWrapperMiddleware> _logger;

    public ResponseWrapperMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        _logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger<ResponseWrapperMiddleware>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {

        try
        {
            var currentBody = httpContext.Response.Body;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //set the current response to the memorystream.
                httpContext.Response.Body = memoryStream;

                await _next(httpContext);

                //reset the body 
                httpContext.Response.Body = currentBody;
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var readToEnd = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
                var objResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(readToEnd);
                var result = CommonApiResponse.Create((HttpStatusCode)httpContext.Response.StatusCode, objResult, null);
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (httpContext.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("The response has already started, the http status code middleware will not be executed.");
                throw;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class ResponseWrapperMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseResponseWrapperMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ResponseWrapperMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

**Generic Response Model**

```cs
public class CommonApiResponse
{
    public static CommonApiResponse Create(HttpStatusCode statusCode, object result = null, string errorMessage = null)
    {
        return new CommonApiResponse(statusCode, result, errorMessage);
    }

    public string Version => "1.2.3";

    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string RequestId { get; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public object Result { get; set; }

    protected CommonApiResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, object result = null, string errorMessage = null)
    {
        RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        Result = result;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

How to handle the error if the route is not found and capture the error in the generic model? What is the workaround for this case?